# How could I add ~ 1 GHz frequency voltage noise of random intensity to a circuit?

Tags: voltage, batteries, noise

I'm a chemist working in battery development, we don't have an electrical engineer on the team which is a bit of a pain.

Anyway, we want to add 1 GHz voltage noise of random intensity to our battery as it charges, in an attempt to suppress dendrites.

Can anyone advise? I know how to solder bits together if there's a certain type of circuit that does this.

Comment: In a lab? I would get a signal generator that can generate 1GHz and has modulation inputs, and feed noise into them (from another function generator maybe).

Comment: Have you considered pulse charging instead with < =1 ns rise time?  Stripline? For reactance control,  arc Discharge ? for fast sub- nanosecond risetime, Coax for EMI control...

Comment: If not pulse then how much of RMS current is microwave?  How about a MH lamp ballast current ? HV igniter and current resonates in UHF depending on gap. What is the battery DC current rating or ESR range?

Comment: Might be useful to specify battery voltage and charging current, as well as intended noise voltage and current levels. As it doesn't need to be random noise, cellphone transmissions may be random enough. Or does it actually need to be noise? Would unmodulated (or on/off modulated) carrier be good enough?

Comment: How did you come up with the information that *1 GHz* noise will suppress the dendrites? It would be much easier for you to design a 100 MHz noise source, or just 1 kHz. Who knows, maybe these "relatively" easy-to-make frequencies are good enough.

Comment: Pulse charging batteries is known to break dendrites such as lead sulphate in car batteries.

Comment: @HarrySvensson How would you know unless you try 1 GHz?

Comment: A key question would be how much noise *power* do you need to achieve the desired result? I suspect that the output of a normal signal generator would not be anywhere near enough, and the design of a microwave power amplifier is far from trivial.

Comment: @pipe Well I wouldn't start at the far end of the spectrum. One of my teachers told me that it's easy to make signals with low-end equipment up to a couple of MHz. If you would want to go beyond that then you had to get some proper knowledge of what you're doing and/or buy more high-end items. OP is a chemist (not an EE) and probably want a cheap answer => A couple of MHz solution. If I want to see if I can walk, then I try to take a couple of steps, I don't run a marathon.

Comment: A few watts broadband up to 1GHz and a source is quite doable - just throw some money at it, if you need many amperes- not so easy. At MHz, much easier. But maybe you can do scaled tests.

Comment: @HarrySvensson A pleasure and a privilege.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies! We charge at about an Amp and are looking for a voltage of about 1.9V with +- 100 mV for the random noise. The noise doesn't have to be random in an intrinsic sense, it just can't be an obviously repeating pattern of fluctuations.

The 1GHz figure comes from a back-of-the-envelope chemical kinetics calculation, if MHz is much cheaper we will go with that, or we'll rent GHz equipment rather than buy it.

Can something maybe be done with a Zener diode and a signal generator? I just read some Wikipedia articles, I have no clue ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can buy commercial RF noise generator (I've used one made by "Noise Com").

Or you can grab a noise generator off of eBay like https://www.ebay.com/itm/172241109978.

To couple the signal in, use a choke in series with the DC supply and a capacitor to couple the noise signal in.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a PRSG (pseudo-random-sequence-generator), and feed 4 bits into a high speed DAC.

Comment: You got flagged for a LQ answer, even if it has some truth to it. The servers do this automatically if the character and line count is not up to preset standards. In the future I would pad it with obvious details to avoid this nuisance flag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. Price wise it's around 5 $, where the op-amp would cost 4$.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%205e-9%202.1831051418620846%2052%205%2050%0Af%20304%20400%20256%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20256%20448%20208%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-0.05599236382977686%0Ac%20256%20448%20304%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-3.6692544482271687%0Aw%20304%20400%20304%20448%200%0Aw%20256%20416%20256%20448%200%0Ag%20256%20448%20256%20464%200%0Aw%20304%20400%20304%20368%200%0Al%20256%20368%20304%20368%200%200.000019999999999999998%200.0004474672088638774%0Aw%20256%20368%20256%20384%200%0Ar%20208%20320%20208%20368%200%201000%0AR%20208%20320%20208%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20256%20368%20208%20368%200%0Aw%20208%20368%20208%20448%200%0Aw%20-80%20368%20-80%20448%200%0Aw%20-32%20368%20-80%20368%200%0AR%20-80%20320%20-80%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20-80%20320%20-80%20368%200%201000%0Aw%20-32%20368%20-32%20384%200%0Al%20-32%20368%2016%20368%200%200.000009999999999999999%20-0.020064995396784836%0Aw%2016%20400%2016%20368%200%0Ag%20-32%20448%20-32%20464%200%0Aw%20-32%20416%20-32%20448%200%0Aw%2016%20400%2016%20448%200%0Ac%20-32%20448%2016%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-1.5973404715000068%0Ac%20-32%20448%20-80%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-1.6362650456790488%0Af%2016%20400%20-32%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Af%20-128%20400%20-176%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20-176%20448%20-224%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-0.37306915961483267%0Ac%20-176%20448%20-128%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-3.214760530201961%0Aw%20-128%20400%20-128%20448%200%0Aw%20-176%20416%20-176%20448%200%0Ag%20-176%20448%20-176%20464%200%0Aw%20-128%20400%20-128%20368%200%0Al%20-176%20368%20-128%20368%200%200.0000049999999999999996%20-0.017609310039236128%0Aw%20-176%20368%20-176%20384%200%0Ar%20-224%20320%20-224%20368%200%201000%0AR%20-224%20320%20-224%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-176%20368%20-224%20368%200%0Aw%20-224%20368%20-224%20448%200%0Aa%20672%20448%20752%20448%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200.9242445315618703%200.9242630164525014%0Aw%2064%20368%2064%20448%200%0Aw%20112%20368%2064%20368%200%0AR%2064%20320%2064%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2064%20320%2064%20368%200%201000%0Aw%20112%20368%20112%20384%200%0Al%20112%20368%20160%20368%200%200.000014999999999999999%200.012489824422810571%0Aw%20160%20400%20160%20368%200%0Ag%20112%20448%20112%20464%200%0Aw%20112%20416%20112%20448%200%0Aw%20160%20400%20160%20448%200%0Ac%20112%20448%20160%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-0.893323206346005%0Ac%20112%20448%2064%20448%200%205.6e-10%20-3.1744842497124894%0Af%20160%20400%20112%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20304%20544%20384%20544%200%201e-8%20-0.17884162461853803%0Af%20432%20544%20480%20544%200%201.5%200.2%0A174%20416%20496%20352%20544%200%201000%200.401%20Resistance%0Ag%20480%20560%20480%20576%200%0AR%20352%20496%20352%20464%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20416%20496%20416%20512%200%0Aw%20384%20544%20432%20544%200%0A174%20480%20528%20512%20464%200%201000%200.9653%20Resistance%0AR%20480%20464%20480%20432%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20752%20400%20752%20448%200%0Ac%20512%20496%20560%20496%200%201e-9%203.9035709955706537%0Ar%20560%20496%20560%20560%200%2010000%0Ag%20560%20560%20560%20576%200%0Ar%20304%20496%20304%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20304%20448%20304%20496%200%0Ar%20160%20496%20160%20544%200%201000%0Aw%2016%20448%2016%20496%200%0Ar%2016%20496%2016%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20-128%20448%20-128%20496%200%0Ar%20-128%20496%20-128%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20-128%20544%2016%20544%200%0Aw%2016%20544%20160%20544%200%0Aw%20160%20544%20304%20544%200%0Ar%20672%20464%20608%20464%200%2010000%0AR%20608%20464%20576%20464%200%200%2040%201.9%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20672%20400%20752%20400%200%201000%0Aw%20672%20400%20672%20432%200%0Ar%20672%20400%20624%20400%200%201000%0Ag%20624%20400%20624%20416%200%0Aw%20672%20496%20560%20496%200%0Aw%20672%20464%20672%20496%200%0Aw%20160%20448%20160%20496%200%0Ax%20-220%20249%20-127%20252%204%2024%20Asin(at)%0Ax%20-76%20250%2017%20253%204%2024%20Bsin(bt)%0Ax%2076%20251%20168%20254%204%2024%20Csin(ct)%0Ax%20209%20254%20304%20257%204%2024%20Dsin(dt)%0Ax%20-155%20596%20319%20599%204%2024%20(Asin(at)%5CpBsin(bt)%5CpCsin(ct)%5CpDsin(dt))/4%0Ax%20381%20470%20462%20473%204%2024%20if(x%3Ey)%0Ax%20715%20507%20909%20510%204%2024%201.9%5Cp(if%5Csresult)*E%0AO%20752%20448%20832%20448%200%0Ao%2071%204%200%204106%207.447472125809951%200.0001%200%202%2071%203%0Ao%2069%204%200%204098%207.486233911202079%200.0001%200%202%2069%203%0Ao%2084%204%200%204098%207.541399654624879%200.0001%200%202%2084%203%0Ao%2067%204%200%204098%207.478076120697935%200.0001%200%202%2067%203%0Ao%2059%204%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%201%202%2059%203%0Ao%2092%204%200%204354%205%200.1%202%201%0A) in case you want to play around with it. You can change the potentiometers values by placing your mouse on top of them and scrolling, or just look to the right at the red bars saying "Resistance" and change them there.

- The graph on the left shows the gate of the 4 oscillators, the node right above their 1 kΩ resistors.
- The graph in the middle shows the gate of the rightmost transistor, it has a threshold voltage of 1.5 V, this means that if it gets some voltage above 1.5 V it will start *activating*.
- The graph on the right shows the "out" node to the far right which is what I assume you will charge your batteries with. Or you can just remove the 1.9 V source and put in your other source that you otherwise use.

The potentiometer below the "*if(x>y)*" text changes the level at when the graph in the middle will turn into a square wave which you can see in the right graph.

The potentiometer to the right of "*if(x>y)*" text changes the amplitude of the noise which you can see in the right graph.

As you can see it's just simply 4 sine wave sources (Colpitts-oscillator) that I'm adding together, then turning into a square wave and finally adding on to 1.9 V. *in my opinion* the graph in the middle is *random* ish, With two sine waves you get something that resembles an annoying fly flying near you.    ....... bzzzzzzzzZZZZZZZZZZZZZzzzzzzz.... bzzzzZZZZZZZZZZzzzzzz.... etc. With three sine waves it's not as random... but with 4 it's... meh, good enough.

And... Yeah... 4.17 MHz is what the highest frequency has in the left graph, sure you can reduce the capacitors and inductor in the oscillators. *But* there's something called "parasitic capacitance" which a MOSFET has a lot of at its gate. I got an [AO3401](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401.pdf) which has an input capacitance of around 645 pF. There are other MOSFET's out there with less gate capacitance..

[Here's](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-arrays/289?FV=ffe00121%2C98c066e%2C98c0823%2C98c0aa1%2C98c0cab%2C98c0cac%2C98c0cad%2C98c0ce4%2C98c0d6c%2C98c0f85%2C98c0f97%2C98c0fa2%2C98c1329%2C98c1358%2C98c1359%2C98c16e1%2C98c0009&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=611&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&cad=0&datasheet=0&nstock=0&photo=0&nonrohs=0&newproducts=0&k=mosfet&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=mosfet) some MOSFET's with a gate capacitance of just 2.5 pF. Not cheap. I get a theoretical 163 MHz (2.5 pF, 2.5 pF, 1 µH).

[Here's](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-arrays/289?FV=98c066e%2C98c0823%2C98c0aa1%2C98c0cab%2C98c0cac%2C98c0cad%2C98c0ce4%2C98c0d6c%2C98c0f85%2C98c0f97%2C98c0fa2%2C98c1329%2C98c1358%2C98c1359%2C98c16e1%2C98c0009%2Cffe00121&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&cad=0&datasheet=0&nstock=0&photo=0&nonrohs=0&newproducts=0&k=mosfet&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=mosfet) some cheap MOSFET's with 7.5 pF gate capacitance and 3.1 output capacitance. If I lower the inductance further to 500 nH I get 151 MHz.

You can easily make a 500 nH air-core coil by winding a wire with very few turns around your finger. Or just a pen. That's what I did.

A 10 nH inductor is practically just a short straight wire.

---

Instead of making 4 oscillators "from scratch", you can instead use [already made](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/oscillators/172?FV=mu1GHz%7C2150%2Cffe000ac&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&cad=0&datasheet=0&nstock=0&photo=0&nonrohs=0&newproducts=0&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=crystal). And sure, then you can get up to your GHz range. But look at the price. It's up to you what "random" is, *in my opinion* it's at least 4 sine waves of different frequencies added together. Look at their size.. good luck soldering that.

So sure, you can replace the part between the 5 V and the 1 kΩ with one of those I just linked. But then you also need a [high speed op-amp](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687?k=op-amp&k=&pkeyword=op-amp&pv2153=u1.2GHz&pv2153=u1.4GHz&pv2153=u1.6GHz&pv2153=u1.8GHz&pv2153=u2GHz&pv2153=u2.2GHz&pv2153=u2.4GHz&FV=mu10GHz%7C658%2Cmu12GHz%7C658%2Cmu18GHz%7C658%2Cmu2.1GHz%7C658%2Cmu2.2GHz%7C658%2Cmu2.8GHz%7C658%2Cmu2GHz%7C658%2Cmu3.9GHz%7C658%2Cmu3GHz%7C658%2Cmu4GHz%7C658%2Cmu8GHz%7C658%2Cffe002af&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25), the ones that work in the GHz range are not the cheapest. Also look at their size, good luck soldering that.

So to wrap up what I said in my first sentence "here's how I'd do it". I'd either do it like [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%205e-11%201.1208435524800693%2052%205%2050%0Ar%20208%20320%20208%20368%200%201000%0AR%20208%20320%20208%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%20-80%20320%20-80%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20-80%20320%20-80%20368%200%201000%0Af%20-128%20400%20-176%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Ac%20-176%20448%20-224%20448%200%203.1e-12%200.11110561272821352%0Ac%20-176%20448%20-128%20448%200%207.5e-12%20-2.9942363731925306%0Aw%20-128%20400%20-128%20448%200%0Aw%20-176%20416%20-176%20448%200%0Ag%20-176%20448%20-176%20464%200%0Aw%20-128%20400%20-128%20368%200%0Al%20-176%20368%20-128%20368%200%201e-8%200.008743423741165438%0Aw%20-176%20368%20-176%20384%200%0Ar%20-224%20320%20-224%20368%200%201000%0AR%20-224%20320%20-224%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-176%20368%20-224%20368%200%0Aw%20-224%20368%20-224%20448%200%0Aa%20672%20448%20752%20448%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200.8854063791327954%200.885424087260378%0AR%2064%20320%2064%20288%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2064%20320%2064%20368%200%201000%0Ac%20304%20544%20384%20544%200%201e-8%200.3394069479743935%0Af%20432%20544%20480%20544%200%201.5%200.2%0A174%20416%20496%20352%20544%200%201000%200.32180000000000003%20Resistance%0Ag%20480%20560%20480%20576%200%0AR%20352%20496%20352%20464%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20416%20496%20416%20512%200%0Aw%20384%20544%20432%20544%200%0A174%20480%20528%20512%20464%200%201000%200.9752000000000001%20Resistance%0AR%20480%20464%20480%20432%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20752%20400%20752%20448%200%0Ac%20512%20496%20560%20496%200%201e-10%203.9934912738215873%0Ar%20560%20496%20560%20560%200%2010000%0Ag%20560%20560%20560%20576%200%0Ar%20304%20496%20304%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20304%20448%20304%20496%200%0Ar%20160%20496%20160%20544%200%201000%0Aw%2016%20448%2016%20496%200%0Ar%2016%20496%2016%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20-128%20448%20-128%20496%200%0Ar%20-128%20496%20-128%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20-128%20544%2016%20544%200%0Aw%2016%20544%20160%20544%200%0Aw%20160%20544%20304%20544%200%0Ar%20672%20464%20608%20464%200%2010000%0AR%20608%20464%20576%20464%200%200%2040%201.9%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20672%20400%20752%20400%200%201000%0Aw%20672%20400%20672%20432%200%0Ar%20672%20400%20624%20400%200%201000%0Ag%20624%20400%20624%20416%200%0Aw%20672%20496%20560%20496%200%0Aw%20672%20464%20672%20496%200%0Aw%20160%20448%20160%20496%200%0Ax%20-220%20249%20-127%20252%204%2024%20Asin(at)%0Ax%20-76%20250%2017%20253%204%2024%20Bsin(bt)%0Ax%2076%20251%20168%20254%204%2024%20Csin(ct)%0Ax%20209%20254%20304%20257%204%2024%20Dsin(dt)%0Ax%20-155%20596%20319%20599%204%2024%20(Asin(at)%5CpBsin(bt)%5CpCsin(ct)%5CpDsin(dt))/4%0Ax%20381%20470%20462%20473%204%2024%20if(x%3Ey)%0Ax%20715%20507%20909%20510%204%2024%201.9%5Cp(if%5Csresult)*E%0AO%20752%20448%20832%20448%200%0Aw%20-80%20368%20-80%20448%200%0Aw%20-32%20368%20-80%20368%200%0Aw%20-32%20368%20-32%20384%200%0Al%20-32%20368%2016%20368%200%202e-8%200.024228820112893668%0Ag%20-32%20448%20-32%20464%200%0Aw%20-32%20416%20-32%20448%200%0Ac%20-32%20448%2016%20448%200%207.5e-12%20-2.764832550200232%0Ac%20-32%20448%20-80%20448%200%203.1e-12%20-0.33764902950401654%0Af%2016%20400%20-32%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%2064%20368%2064%20448%200%0Aw%20112%20368%2064%20368%200%0Aw%20112%20368%20112%20384%200%0Al%20112%20368%20160%20368%200%204e-8%20-0.023060805552285322%0Ag%20112%20448%20112%20464%200%0Aw%20112%20416%20112%20448%200%0Ac%20112%20448%20160%20448%200%207.5e-12%20-2.2654139929358306%0Ac%20112%20448%2064%20448%200%203.1e-12%20-1.386966037125458%0Af%20160%20400%20112%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20208%20368%20208%20448%200%0Aw%20256%20368%20208%20368%200%0Aw%20256%20368%20256%20384%200%0Al%20256%20368%20304%20368%200%208e-8%20-0.012078750758499622%0Ag%20256%20448%20256%20464%200%0Aw%20256%20416%20256%20448%200%0Ac%20256%20448%20304%20448%200%207.5e-12%20-1.285425310087812%0Ac%20256%20448%20208%20448%200%203.1e-12%20-3.832507542529685%0Af%20304%20400%20256%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%2016%20368%2016%20400%200%0Aw%2016%20400%2016%20448%200%0Aw%20160%20448%20160%20400%200%0Aw%20160%20400%20160%20368%200%0Aw%20304%20368%20304%20400%200%0Aw%20304%20400%20304%20448%200%0Ao%2038%201%200%204106%203.7237360629049756%200.0001%200%202%2038%203%0Ao%2036%201%200%204098%203.7431169556010393%200.0001%200%202%2036%203%0Ao%2051%201%200%204098%203.7706998273124395%200.0001%200%202%2051%203%0Ao%2034%201%200%204098%203.7390380603489675%200.0001%200%202%2034%203%0Ao%2026%201%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%201%202%2026%203%0Ao%2059%201%200%204354%202.5%200.1%202%201%0A) or like [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5e-11+1.1208435524800693+52+5+50%0Ar+336+272+336+320+0+1000%0AR+336+272+336+240+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AR+48+272+48+240+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+48+272+48+320+0+1000%0Af+0+352+-48+352+0+1.5+0.02%0Ac+-48+400+-96+400+0+3.1e-12+-3.1663580955090813%0Ac+-48+400+0+400+0+7.5e-12+-1.7014522173714992%0Aw+0+352+0+400+0%0Aw+-48+368+-48+400+0%0Ag+-48+400+-48+416+0%0Aw+0+352+0+320+0%0Al+-48+320+0+320+0+1e-8+0.04446098303964182%0Aw+-48+320+-48+336+0%0Ar+-96+272+-96+320+0+1000%0AR+-96+272+-96+240+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-48+320+-96+320+0%0Aw+-96+320+-96+400+0%0Aa+672+448+752+448+0+15+-15+1000000+0.967236354951337+0.967255699678436%0AR+192+272+192+240+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+192+272+192+320+0+1000%0Ac+480+496+560+496+0+1e-9+1.179246157582152%0Aw+752+400+752+448+0%0Ar+560+496+560+560+0+1000%0Ag+560+560+560+576+0%0Ar+432+448+432+496+0+47000%0Aw+432+400+432+448+0%0Ar+288+448+288+496+0+47000%0Aw+144+400+144+448+0%0Ar+144+448+144+496+0+47000%0Aw+0+400+0+448+0%0Ar+0+448+0+496+0+47000%0Aw+0+496+144+496+0%0Aw+144+496+288+496+0%0Aw+288+496+432+496+0%0Ar+672+464+608+464+0+1000%0AR+608+464+576+464+0+0+40+1.9+0+0+0.5%0Ar+672+400+752+400+0+1000%0Aw+672+400+672+432+0%0Ar+672+400+624+400+0+1000%0Ag+624+400+624+416+0%0Aw+672+496+560+496+0%0Aw+672+464+672+496+0%0Aw+288+400+288+448+0%0Ax+-92+201+1+204+4+24+Asin(at)%0Ax+52+202+145+205+4+24+Bsin(bt)%0Ax+204+203+296+206+4+24+Csin(ct)%0Ax+337+206+432+209+4+24+Dsin(dt)%0Ax+-27+548+447+551+4+24+(Asin(at)%5CpBsin(bt)%5CpCsin(ct)%5CpDsin(dt))/4%0Ax+715+507+909+510+4+24+1.9%5Cp(if%5Csresult)*E%0AO+752+448+832+448+0%0Aw+48+320+48+400+0%0Aw+96+320+48+320+0%0Aw+96+320+96+336+0%0Al+96+320+144+320+0+2e-8+0.03016429431717839%0Ag+96+400+96+416+0%0Aw+96+368+96+400+0%0Ac+96+400+144+400+0+7.5e-12+-2.6746552990994825%0Ac+96+400+48+400+0+3.1e-12+-0.6540123344373721%0Af+144+352+96+352+0+1.5+0.02%0Aw+192+320+192+400+0%0Aw+240+320+192+320+0%0Aw+240+320+240+336+0%0Al+240+320+288+320+0+4e-8+-0.00646086473699728%0Ag+240+400+240+416+0%0Aw+240+368+240+400+0%0Ac+240+400+288+400+0+7.5e-12+-3.134681185044529%0Ac+240+400+192+400+0+3.1e-12+-0.14849193313265%0Af+288+352+240+352+0+1.5+0.02%0Aw+336+320+336+400+0%0Aw+384+320+336+320+0%0Aw+384+320+384+336+0%0Al+384+320+432+320+0+8e-8+-0.01636963978893348%0Ag+384+400+384+416+0%0Aw+384+368+384+400+0%0Ac+384+400+432+400+0+7.5e-12+-2.6972544970352166%0Ac+384+400+336+400+0+3.1e-12+-0.7726973515041199%0Af+432+352+384+352+0+1.5+0.02%0Aw+144+320+144+352+0%0Aw+144+352+144+400+0%0Aw+288+400+288+352+0%0Aw+288+352+288+320+0%0Aw+432+320+432+352+0%0Aw+432+352+432+400+0%0Aw+480+496+432+496+0%0Ao+29+1+0+4106+3.7237360629049756+0.0001+0+2+29+3%0Ao+27+1+0+4098+3.7431169556010393+0.0001+0+2+27+3%0Ao+42+1+0+4098+3.7706998273124395+0.0001+0+2+42+3%0Ao+25+1+0+4098+3.7390380603489675+0.0001+0+2+25+3%0Ao+49+1+0+4354+3.9437792269934957+0.0001+1+1%0A).